# Invalid use of void expression; copying info from array pointed to by void pointer; into array pointed to by char-pointer

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I want to store all of the data that is kept in encoding_symbols_tab [0] in symbol_and_header.
'encoding_symbols_tab' points to an array with e.g. 500 * 1024 chars.

I modified the following code for this example.

```
void** encoding_symbols_tab;

(..)

char* return_symbol_and_header_array ()
    { //abcd
    char* symbol_and_header =  (char*)calloc(1, 1024 + 14 );
    (..)   
    int k=0;
    for (k=0; k < 1024; k++)
    {
    symbol_and_header [k+14] = (char) encoding_symbols_tab [0][k];
    }

    return symbol_and_header;
    }
```

When I run this code I get 'error: invalid use of void expression'
How should I change the code in order to resolve this (without changing the type of 'void** encoding_symbols_tab').?
It is a C-program.

Comment: How `encoding_symbols_tab` is filled up? What does it contain?

Comment: try `((char **) encoding_symbols_tab) [0][k]`

Comment: FYI, you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` (or `calloc()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
((char**)encoding_symbols_tab) [0][k];
```

Answer (score 1):

If `encoding_symbols_tab` points to characters, why do you declare it as pointing to `void *`s? You cannot dereference a `void *` pointer because it doesn't point to data of any type.

You could declare `char **encoding_symbols_tab` instead of `void **encoding_symbols_tab`, but, first, make sure that's what it really points to. In your question you suggest that it might be something else:

- If `encoding_symbols_tab` points to a flat array of 500 * 1024 characters (i.e. 512000 characters) then you must:

  - Declare `encoding_symbols_tab` as `char *`
  - Reference its elements as `encoding_symbols_tab[x*1024+k]`
- If `encoding_symbols_tab` points to an array of 500 `char *` pointers which themselves each point to an array of 1024 characters, then you must:

  - Declare `encoding_symbols_tab` as `char **`
  - Reference its elements as `encoding_symbols_tab[x][k]`

assuming `x` is the first dimension (out of 500) and `k` is the second dimension (out of 1024).